# Configuring routing protocols

Tags: routing

I would like to know if I can configure a routing protocol, for instance OSPF, EIGRP, or Ripv2 with out a physical address configured to the any interfaces. But then again by not configuring a IP address to the physical interfaces connected to each network using Either routing protocol, then they won't be able to communicate? Is this correct? I'm not actually in front of a network to test this.

Comment: are you try loopback interface ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cisco has the `ip unnumbered` command that allows an interface to assume the address of another interface for distance-vector routing protocols.  If the requirement is no IP address assignment on a physical interface, you could assign a loopback with an IP address and use the `ip unnumbered Loopback<num>` on the physical interface.

The physical interfaces could also use DHCP to get an IP address.

The interfaces need some sort of IP address, specifically assigned, or not.  Routing can't work without knowing IP addressing.  Routing without IP addressing is like the post office needing to deliver mail without knowing a street address, city, or state.  It's just not going to happen.

Comment: Your conclusion answers my question. Thanks man.